Disabling DNSSEC Route53
I want to disable DNSSEC on my domain which is registered via AWS and managed via Route53. The reason is we want to switch to Cloudflare for DDOS protection.
In the following guide they are mentioning that I need to remove the DS key from the parent zone. If I understand this correctly, I need to go to Registered domains > DNSSEC keys and remove the DNSSEC key over there. When the TTL is expired, I can click on "Disable DNSSEC signing". As this operation can be very dangerous I would like to have some confirmation on this.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/configuring-dnssec-signing-and-validation-with-amazon-route-53/#:~:text=To%20turn%20off%20DNSSEC%20for,want%20to%20disable%20DNSSEC%20signing.
The thing I don't understand is, when I remove the DNSSEC key it will eventually break the chain of trust, so that will also make my domain unavailable right?
Can anyone please confirm with me what the correct order will be for disabling DNSSEC signing for a domain where the registrar is also AWS?
Thanks in advance!

I managed to fix this together with a sysops guy. He told me that for the chain of trust, first the registrar is queried and then it's validated with the DNS. So in my case I can just remove the DS key from the registrar (AWS) and wait till TTL has expired.
